# Prevent default “Enter Parameter Value” C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a form with CrystalReportViewer and on the top there are two DateTimePickers with on button for generating a crystal report with the selected date range, this is my code its work, but my question is how can I Prevent default "Enter Parameter Value" dialog box display, because I want to use only my datetimepickers.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument RepDoc = new ReportDocument();
            RepDoc.Load(@"C:****I Put the path of report here");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"I Put the Data Source here");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Items", con);
            StockDBDataSet ds = new StockDBDataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds, "Items");
            RepDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
            ParameterFieldDefinitions ParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition ParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues ParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue ParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            ParameterDiscreteValue.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            ParameterFieldDefinitions = RepDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            ParameterFieldDefinition = ParameterFieldDefinitions["Start_Date"];
            ParameterValues = ParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            ParameterValues.Clear();
            ParameterValues.Add(ParameterDiscreteValue);
            ParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(ParameterValues);

            ParameterDiscreteValue.Value = dateTimePicker2.Value;
            ParameterFieldDefinitions = RepDoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            ParameterFieldDefinition = ParameterFieldDefinitions["End_Date"];
            ParameterValues = ParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            ParameterValues.Clear();
            ParameterValues.Add(ParameterDiscreteValue);
            ParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(ParameterValues);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RepDoc;

        }
```

Comment: I remove it and the dialog is still appear

Comment: Check this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/33185985/5104101. Note `reset the collections` in the `adding SECOND parameter` block. To avoid collisions, I would recommend NOT to name your variables, class, controls as the names of keywords, inbuilt class names etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try including this line.

```
 crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = RepDoc.ParameterFields;
```

This I reckon should do it for you.