# How to set path of Project folder in crystal report Picture Field

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to change image in my crystal report dynamically in my Asp.net Project. So I used Picture field and set the path in "Graphic Location".

It's working fine when I give the path of external image like this "F:\abc.jpg".

But I want to give the path of image which is inside my project let's say I have a folder in my project "Images" which contains all images. So I want to set path like this "Images/abc.jpg"

How can I do this ?

Comment: You can follow steps in this article [crystal-reports-dynamic-images](http://www.cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/). As mentioned in a step you can **set the formula's text to the name of the formula or parameter field**, set the parameter field value to your required folder in asp.net and use this folder path in combination with file name to produce image path.

Comment: Hi @haraman
Thanks for your reply. I know how to set formula and parameter field. But I want to set path of my Project folder as I discussed in my Question.

Comment: Thats what I said in my comment. 1) Create a ParameterField in report design e.g. `imagepath` 2) Set the Graphic Location of your picture field as formula using the Parameter e.g. `{?imagePath}/image_name.jpg` 3) From your asp.net set the value of imagepath report parameter as your desired folder/image as in [how-to-pass-values-to-two-different-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127714/how-to-pass-values-to-two-different-parameters/33185985#33185985)