# Strange image behavior on crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I have the following code:

```
string foto = "D:\\PRP System\\BD\\modelos\\" + mv.modelo.foto.Replace("D:/PRP System/BD/modelos/", "");
iv.SetParameterValue("pctFoto", foto);
```

When I manually input the crystal image parameter, the image shows on my report, but when I use the code above it doesn't show the image.
The code bellow works fine and shows it.

```
iv.SetParameterValue("pctFoto", "D:\\PRP System\\BD\\modelos\\tc1.jpg");
```

On the report I have a picture with a function feeding this image url.

Comment: Did you check the value for "foto" after you assigned it?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly same string value

Comment: for the image, rathar than hardcore/physical (d /c drive ) path, give the relative path likeserver.mappath / app.setting / etc. check the link - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f869fe3f-ee0f-4ecd-ae7c-9303e0b1f66f/dynamic-image-location-by-using-a-parameter?forum=vscrystalreports, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559554/how-to-set-path-of-project-folder-in-crystal-report-picture-field